# Spring template Hello world project does not work

Tags: java, spring-mvc, taglib, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am learning Spring STS and trying to create simple web project. I have selected Spring Template Project -> Spring MVC Project, filled names and clicked "Finish". I did nothing more with the project, but it have an error in it from the very beginning:

Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"

This is about `home.jsp` file wizard created. So why don't they put library descriptor while referencing it in template?

**EDIT1**

If I run this program, I get error 404 `http://localhost:8080/<appname>/` not found.

From log:

WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [`<appname>`] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'

Comment: did u add jstl.jar, standard.jar in your buildpath.

Comment: No, I didn't. I was thinking a wizard or Maven should. Am I wrong?

Comment: i don't know how Maven works, But the error clearly shows that both jars are missing from your build path.

Comment: I wish to learn Spring+Maven, but as for now noticing they are full of glitches. I looked and saw I have jstl-1.2.jar added by Maven.

Comment: ok, check the taglib uri in that jar..

Comment: I see there `META-INF/c.tld` file which says `<uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core</uri>`, which looks correct.

Comment: @SuzanCioc "Full of glitches"? In what way?

Comment: @Dave You can browse my questions. Several of them dedicated to this.

Comment: @Dave for example is this question: the inital project created by wizard appeares broken.

Comment: @SuzanCioc It seems more like unfamiliarity with Spring and Maven.

Comment: @Dave can you then find my mistake in the question above, please?

Comment: @SuzanCioc I don't use the STS very often, and have no idea what's required for their "template project". I'd turn logging up to debug level and see what's in the startup logs. The error message suggests things haven't been configured correctly, though, or you're not accessing a valid URL. "Running" a web app means the server spins up and you make requests to it; if you request an invalid URL, that's the message you'll get.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue, here is the solution:

For the first issue:
In order to fix the error above right click on the webapp directory in your project explorer and select Build Path –> Click Use as Source Folder. What this does is add the webapp directory to the build path which ensures our webapp files are included in the deployment.

For your second issue 'Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"'
Sometimes i notice STS doesnt build all the files initially in the template, so just go to home.jsp and re-save it.

I wrote a tutorial on this subject that might help you also:

http://devhub.fm/?p=56

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As per [this post](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?121871-STS-2-8-1-Cannot-quot-Open-Home-Page-quot-for-new-Spring-MVC-app-get-Status-404), *Project > Clean* within STS resolved this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved for me ...Actually while creating Spring MVC Project using sts it prompts for project/application name and also the package name. So if project name is TestPayments and package name is com.xyz.payments then after creating the project when you run the project and hit the url as localhost:8080/TestPayments it says resource not found or 404. But actually it works as localhost:8080/payments

While creating the project it creates the artifactId as "payments" in your pom.xml (based on the package name)

Not sure why but it works like that.